# Android:save the checkbox state and find the checkbox location

Tags: android, checkbox

i want to save my checkbox state using save preference method so when i closed the application the checked items are still there, but the problem i encouter is that i cannot get the checkbox array location or checkbox index, please help me with these

heres my main activity program

```
  package com.example.cameraapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class FinalChoice extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
     CheckBox checkbox;
     List<File> lst;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    Button save;
    ContextWrapper context;
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview1hold);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,getModel());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener((android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {



                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FUCKYOU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });

    }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
                TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.songsTexView);
checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.checkBox1);
  Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), label.getText().toString()+" "+isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
        if(checkbox.isChecked())
        return "is checked";
        else
        return "is not checked";
    }
    private List<Model> getModel() {

         String mp3Directory = "/Music";
         String directoryPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+mp3Directory;
         lst = getMP3Files(directoryPath); 

        //print in LogCat the list of .mp3:
        for(int a=0;a<lst.size();a++){
        list.add(new Model(lst.get(a).getName()));

        }
          return list;

            }

    public List<File> getMP3Files(String directory) {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        File folder = new File(directory);
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || file.getName().endsWith(".MP3")) {
                    files.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
    public void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
        }
}
```

Comment: ajuju, any error are you getting when saving or fetching the data, can you please ellaborate?

Comment: What you are getting when you restart the app as you have mentioned ?

Comment: what i wanna do exactly is when i checked the item and hit the save button the selected items will be restored so when i close the app the item that i select is still checked @DeepMehta, And now to be exact i dont know what to do because savereference required something about the exact location of the checked checkboxbutton

Comment: You can do that!! As you have mentioned in your question, you just have to create an array which contains the position & boolean(For checked or not). Now, when you hit save button, you just have to save that array in SharedPref. Now, when you restart your app, you can get the array from sharedPref and check that which are checked and which are not!!!!!!